# asp.net c# advanced searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

on a site im currently, as you can see repeating out all profiles from the database.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <ItemTemplate>

               <div class="profilbox">
                    <div id="billedeSmall">
                        <img alt="" src="prod_image/<%#Eval ("bruger_billede") %>" width="100" height="100" />
                        </div>
                <h3><%# Eval("bruger_fornavn") %><br /><%# Eval("bruger_efternavn") %></h3>
                <p>Alder: <%# Eval("bruger_alder") %>år.<br />Søger: <%# Eval("bruger_søger") %><br />Kommune: <%# Eval("bruger_kommune") %>
                   <br /><a href="profilNormal.aspx?id=<%#Eval("bruger_id") %>">...Vis profil</a></p>

            </div>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT  * FROM brugere ORDER BY NEWID()"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**and here a table with 1 drop down for "show profiles that are searching for" a row with 2 texboxes that are ment to be age between textbox1 and textbox2 and a last textbox where you can search for area.**

```
<table class="auto-style3">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">vis profiler der søger:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>mand</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>kvinde</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">age between: </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            og<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style5">i kommunen:</td>
        <td class="auto-style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Søg" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and that is sadly all i have as i dont know where to start in code behind.  i wanted it to work like : if you choose "male" in the dropdownlist and click the botton, show all profiles that have  "male"  in the database column called "looking for" or the other way around ofcourse.

and then if you enter something in age between: textbox4 and textbox5 show all profiles that then are male, and between say 20 and 30 if that is what the user entered in the two textboxes. does this make sense? im still a beginner in ASP.net c#. im sorry if this is not a real question.

i now started on codebehind, is this the right idea? and can anyone tell me how i should show the results on my page? again im still new so please bear with me.

```
 protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string statement = @"SELECT * FROM brugere";

        string whereConcatenator = "WHERE ";

        if (DropDownListSøger.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            statement += whereConcatenator;
            statement += "bruger_søger= '" + DropDownListSøger.SelectedItem.Value + "' ";

            whereConcatenator = "OR ";
        }

       if (TextBoxKommune.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            statement += whereConcatenator;
            statement += "bruger_kommune LIKE '%" + TextBoxKommune.Text + "%' ";

            whereConcatenator = "OR ";
        }


        Response.Write(statement);

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, Conn);

        Conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {

        }
```

picture of the site to get a better illustration: [image: search]

Comment: I think you need to start on your Button1_Click event on code behind. Basically, you build around the logic by checking dropdown selected value, textbox inputs and search on your database based on those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it almost works with this, but " kommune " still is not working 100 %

protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string statement = @"SELECT * FROM brugere";

    string whereConcatenator = " WHERE ";

    if (DropDownListSøger.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        statement += whereConcatenator;
        statement += "bruger_søger ='" + DropDownListSøger.SelectedItem.Value + "' ";

        whereConcatenator = "AND ";
    }


    if (TextBox_AlderFra.Text != "")
      {

         statement += whereConcatenator;
         statement += " bruger_alder BETWEEN '" + TextBox_AlderFra.Text + "' AND '" + TextBox_AlderTil.Text + "'";
         whereConcatenator = "AND ";

     }
    if (TextBoxKommune.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        statement += whereConcatenator;
        statement += "bruger_kommune = '%" + TextBoxKommune.Text + "%' ";

    }

   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = statement;


}
```